# C# Capture HTTP response when the page is fully loaded

Tags: c#, http, post

I want to send a http post request and capture the response. I have written following code.

```
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);
   req.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy(ProxyString, true);
   //Add these, as we're doing a POST
   req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   req.Method = "POST";
   //We need to count how many bytes we're sending. 
   //Post'ed Faked Forms should be name=value&
   byte [] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
   req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
   System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream ();
   os.Write (bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
   os.Close ();
   System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
   if (resp== null) return null;
   System.IO.StreamReader sr = 
         new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
   return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

**Update 1:**

I tried making use of PostAsync method. Still the same result.

```
public static async void Req()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { "type1", "val1" },
       { "type2", "val2" },
       { "type3", "val3"}
    };
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
                var r1 = await client.PostAsync(URL, content);

                var responseString = await r1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseString);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

But its capturing only partial response. My Page takes 10-12 seconds to load. How do I make my script wait and capture complete response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working code. Just pass the correct parameters to the method.

```
public static async void Req()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
             { "type1", "val1" },
             { "type2", "val2" },
             { "type3", "val3"}
        };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var r1 = await client.PostAsync(URL, content);

            var responseString = await r1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to that the response is encoded in som other encoding then UTF8 that StreamReader defaults to. Please check the encoding of the response and alter the call to streamreader from

```
new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
```

to

```
new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
```

for ASCII encoding

Comment: The second approach i posted is working for me. Earlier I provided incorrect parameter value. Async call did the trick